# How is a long call and short stock portfolio equivalent to lending money

Tags: options, volatility

In his book 'Volatility Trading' Euan Sinclair writes that a hedged portfolio of long call and short stock is equivalent to lending money.

He did not provide much clarification, so I am wondering, how is it equivalent to lending money?

Comment: Synthetic "Long Put". Best write the author.

Answer (score 2):

hmmm. I think it's because in both cases, you must pay for it up front, before the positions are closed out. You own nothing except the *right* to buy the stock re: the call, and the *obligation* to buy the stock re: the short. 
You buy a call, but must borrow the stock, for which you must put some margin collateral and there is a cost to borrow. You pay for that, of course. 
I wouldn't call it lending though.

Answer (score 1):

A long call and short stock portfolio is NOT equivalent to "lending money".  Either your quote is missing some information or the author is incorrect.

As Optionparty correctly stated in his comment (without explaining it), this posiition is equivalent to a Synthetic Long Put which means that the position performs the same as if you had just bought a put with the same strike and expiration.

For future reference, there are 6 basic synthetic positions relating to combinations of put options, call options and their underlying stock in accordance to the Synthetic Triangle:

1. Synthetic Long Stock = Long Call + Short Put
2. Synthetic Short Stock = Short Call + Long Put
3. Synthetic Long Call = Long Stock + Long Put
4. Synthetic Short Call = Short Stock + Short Put
5. Synthetic Short Put = Long Stock + Short Call
6. Synthetic Long Put = Short Stock + Long Call